# Using google geoCode occasionally returns ZERO_RESULT

Tags: google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I am calling `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=37.5,-77.5&key=<key>`

to get the actual address from long/lat for a coordinate.

However, it seems that google occasionally sends me

{"results":[],"status":"ZERO_RESULTS"}

What are some of the reasons that this may occur? In this particular case, 37.5 and -77.5 (i rounded it into 1 decimal) is the exact parameter that I sent. And i got zero_result from my actual production server. But currently when I tried it in my local environment, it actually gives me the correct addresss.

Are there something that i missed that could result in the production getting ZERO_RESULT?

Thanks

Comment: In [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse) you should use `latlng` parameter instead of the `address` parameter. Is it still reproducible when you use `latlng`?

Comment: Interesting.. Let me try to use latlng instead.